# Regex get speical characters between two strings

Tags: regex, string, character

hello i want to match every characters between two strings then save special characters to call it example
"`{code}watch?=123ashjQ{/code}`"
so i want to match this then save "`123ashjq`" as `$1`

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
\}.*?=(.*?)\{
```

https://regex101.com/r/hJ6jX5/1

Answer (score 0):

Try with regex negation [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH9mM3/2)

```
\}[^=]+=([^{]+)\{
```